# Springer MathPhys Style in LaTeX

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

The editor of a Springer book I am contributing to asked me to format citations according to the [MathPhys Style](https://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/Key_Style_Points_MathPhysRef.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1330670-0). I wrote my chapter in LaTeX and I have all my references in a `bib` file. I could not find any `bst` file to format citations according to MathPhys Style rules.

As far as I know, the only way to get author-year references with the `svmult` class is to use `spbasic.bst` along with the `natbib` package, but the references are not formatted as required. I did not find any hint in Springer's website. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please double-check your link to the style, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Link corrected. From `spmpsci.bst` I read `% This is a numerical citation style, and as such is standard LaTeX.`. So, I suppose it is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, please have a closer look to  [Springer web side](https://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/book-authors-editors/manuscript-preparation/5636).  There you can find (open "Reference List"):

> For authors using BiBTeX, the style files are included in Springer's
>   LaTeX package.

That means just use one of the given styles (for example `spbasic.bst`) there best matching to what you need.  The last work is done by the journal ...

Answer (score 0):

As I believe, the answer is not correct: "Hamburger, C.: Quasimonotonicity, regularity and duality for nonlinear systems of partial
differential equations. Ann. Mat. Pura. Appl. 169, 321–354 (1995)"
includes the paper title, but Springer `\documentclass[graybox]{svmult}` together with any of Springer .bst packages drop the title